# R: do calculation for each factor level separately, then calculate min/mean/max over levels

Tags: r, factors, levels

So I do have the output of a water distribution model, which is inflow and discharge values of a river for every hour. I have done 5 model runs

reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(rep(seq(
                  from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:00", tz="UTC"),
                  to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 23:00", tz="UTC"),
                  by="hour"
                  ),5),
                as.factor(c(rep(1,24),rep(2,24),rep(3,24), rep(4,24),rep(5,24))),
                rep(seq(1,300,length.out=24),5),
                rep(seq(1,180, length.out=24),5) )

colnames(df)<-c("time", "run", "inflow", "discharge")
```

In reality, of course, the values for the runs are varying. (And I do have a lot of more data, as I do have 100 runs and hourly values of 35 years).

So, at first I would like to calculate a water scarcity factor for every run, which means I need to calculate something like (1 - (discharge / inflow of 6 hours before)), as the water needs 6 hours to run through the catchment.

```
 scarcityfactor <- 1 - (discharge / lag(inflow,6))
```

And then I want to calculate to a mean, max and min of scarcity factors over all runs (to find out the highest, the lowest and mean value of scarcity that could happen at every time step; according to the different model runs). So I would say, I could just calculate a mean, max and min for every time step:

```
f1 <- function(x) c(Mean = (mean(x)), Max = (max(x)), Min = (min(x)))
results <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(scarcityfactor ~ time, 
      data = df,                                                              
      FUN = f1))
```

Can anybody help me with the code??

Comment: protip: instead of `as.factor(c(rep(...), ...))`, use `gl(5, 24)`

Comment: You should provide an ideal output for the data you provided. I posted a solution that will help you, but it seems you have the same values for each `time`.

Comment: AntoniosK: Thank you a lot! Your solution is working fine. Sorry, I didn't know how to create varying inflow and discharge without doing a lot of typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(run) %>%
  mutate(scarcityfactor = 1 - discharge / lag(inflow,6)) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(scarcityfactor), 
            Max = max(scarcityfactor), 
            Min = min(scarcityfactor))

# # A tibble: 24 x 4
#  time                   Mean     Max     Min
#  <dttm>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 2012-01-01 00:00:00  NA      NA      NA    
# 2 2012-01-01 01:00:00  NA      NA      NA    
# 3 2012-01-01 02:00:00  NA      NA      NA    
# 4 2012-01-01 03:00:00  NA      NA      NA    
# 5 2012-01-01 04:00:00  NA      NA      NA    
# 6 2012-01-01 05:00:00  NA      NA      NA    
# 7 2012-01-01 06:00:00 -46.7   -46.7   -46.7  
# 8 2012-01-01 07:00:00  -2.96   -2.96   -2.96 
# 9 2012-01-01 08:00:00  -1.34   -1.34   -1.34 
#10 2012-01-01 09:00:00  -0.776  -0.776  -0.776
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want, if I understand the problem description correctly.

I'll use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# add scarcity_factor (group by run)
df[ , scarcity_factor := 1 - discharge/shift(inflow, 6L), by = run]

# group by time, excluding times for which the
#   scarcity factor is missing
df[!is.na(scarcity_factor), by = time,
   .(min_scarcity = min(scarcity_factor),
     mean_scarcity = mean(scarcity_factor),
     max_scarcity = max(scarcity_factor))]

#                    time  min_scarcity mean_scarcity  max_scarcity
#  1: 2012-01-01 06:00:00 -46.695652174 -46.695652174 -46.695652174
#  2: 2012-01-01 07:00:00  -2.962732919  -2.962732919  -2.962732919
#  3: 2012-01-01 08:00:00  -1.342995169  -1.342995169  -1.342995169
#  4: 2012-01-01 09:00:00  -0.776086957  -0.776086957  -0.776086957
#  5: 2012-01-01 10:00:00  -0.487284660  -0.487284660  -0.487284660
#  6: 2012-01-01 11:00:00  -0.312252964  -0.312252964  -0.312252964
#  7: 2012-01-01 12:00:00  -0.194826637  -0.194826637  -0.194826637
#  8: 2012-01-01 13:00:00  -0.110586011  -0.110586011  -0.110586011
#  9: 2012-01-01 14:00:00  -0.047204969  -0.047204969  -0.047204969
# 10: 2012-01-01 15:00:00   0.002210759   0.002210759   0.002210759
# 11: 2012-01-01 16:00:00   0.041818785   0.041818785   0.041818785
# 12: 2012-01-01 17:00:00   0.074275362   0.074275362   0.074275362
# 13: 2012-01-01 18:00:00   0.101356965   0.101356965   0.101356965
# 14: 2012-01-01 19:00:00   0.124296675   0.124296675   0.124296675
# 15: 2012-01-01 20:00:00   0.143977192   0.143977192   0.143977192
# 16: 2012-01-01 21:00:00   0.161047028   0.161047028   0.161047028
# 17: 2012-01-01 22:00:00   0.175993343   0.175993343   0.175993343
# 18: 2012-01-01 23:00:00   0.189189189   0.189189189   0.189189189
```

You can be a tad more concise by `lapply`ing over different aggregators:

```
df[!is.na(scarcity_factor), by = time,
   lapply(list(min, mean, max), function(f) f(scarcity_factor))]
```

Lastly you could think of this as reshaping with aggregation and use `dcast`:

```
dcast(df, time ~ ., value.var = 'scarcity_factor',
      fun.aggregate = list(min, mean, max))
```

(use `df[!is.na(scarcity_factor)]` in the first argument of `dcast` if you want to exclude the meaningless rows)